# Cannot use "link_to" or "button_to" in Rails 4.2 with Semantic-UI

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using Semantic-UI for designing my rails app design. I have created a card layout with a button attached in the bottom of that card. But When I tries to add link_to or button_to to my text in the bottom attached button everything gets spoils.

### HTML + Rails 4.2 Code Written:

```
<div class="ui four cards">
        <a class="red card">
            <div class="image">
                <%= image_tag("white-image.png") %>
            </div>
            <div class="ui bottom attached button">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i><span class="little-space"></span><%= link_to 'Deploy', controller: 'apps', action: 'show'%>

            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Output:

[image: Try 1]

Must look like this:

[image: Original]

---

Normal HTML and CSS works but when I try to use Rails4.2 helpers like "link_to" or "button_to" then everything gets wrong. Is there any way through which I can make whole card layout as clickable using Rails helper.

---

Generated HTML Code:

```
<div class="ui four cards">
        <a class="red card">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/assets/white-image-d3f1bf0d70bdd663809bc001a778b550fc7246e81a614f3ff10e7cfb0a1514cf.png" alt="White image d3f1bf0d70bdd663809bc001a778b550fc7246e81a614f3ff10e7cfb0a1514cf">
            </div>
            </a><div class="ui bottom attached button"><a class="red card">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i><span class="little-space"></span></a><a href="/apps/show">Delpoy</a>

            </div>

    </div>
```

---

Simple output using HTML and Semantic-UI

```html
<link href="http://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui four cards">
     <a class="red card">
       <div class="image">
        <img class="ui wireframe image" src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/white-image.png">
       </div>
       <div class="ui bottom attached button">
          <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i><span class="little-space"></span>Deploy
          
       </div>
      </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: How does the generated HTML looks like? Please create a demo of the issue.

Comment: Did you try class option for link_to like `<%= link_to 'Deploy', controller: 'apps', action: 'show', {class: '<css-class>'}%>` , as you said normal html and css works.

Comment: With normal html and css I mean that I am not using link_to tag.

Comment: I also tried {html code here}.html_safe but same output comes. Let me try your suggestion. Then I will inform you

Comment: I tries your suggestion but nothing happened. Same output is rendering.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a missing pieces of view code in your question? there are two `<a class="red card">` in the generated html and only one in the view code.

Comment: Is it possible to create a js fiddle with normal html and css which is working so that a similar railsy way can be suggested?

Comment: ok let me try to do that for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and `button_to` both accept a block which can be used to insert arbitrary content inside the link/button.

```
<div class="ui four cards">
  <%= link_to({ controller: 'apps', action: 'show' }, { class: "red card" }) do %>
    <div class="image">
      <%= image_tag "white-image.png", class: "ui wireframe image" %>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached button">
      <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i><span class="little-space"></span>Deploy
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great!!! Can you tell me what does "ui wireframe image" class works? I didn't found it at Semantic-UI website.

Answer (score 2):

`link_to` can accept a block, try this:

```
<div class="ui four cards">
    <%= link_to {controller: 'apps', action: 'show'}, {class: "red card"} do %>
        <div class="image">
            <%= image_tag("white-image.png") %>
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached button">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
        <span class="little-space"></span>
            Deploy
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```